# BigCommerce user defined custom fields for address and customer

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I need to retrieve custom field values for customers and addresses using the Big Commerce API.

There appears to be a facility for this for custom product fields;

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/custom_fields

However no documentation exists for customers and addresses. I tried to access with a similar URL to the products custom fields URL (ie. GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/customers/{customer_id}/custom_fields) with no success

I realise a similair question has been asked on here already, however BigCommerce support asked me to ask the question on here and that a developer will respond. Here's hoping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no endpoint for custom fields on customers/addresses through the BC API. Hopefully that will be something they'll add when they come out with the next version of their API

Comment: Yeah it looks that way. I managed to work around it by hijacking core fields which were not being used and re-purposing them. Appreciate the response.

Comment: @RichardClark awesome, glad you made that work. Maybe the address line 2 or something?

Comment: I used the State/Province field. We don't really need that in the UK.