# How do I update 'Address Type' in address using API?

Tags: bigcommerce

How can I update 'Address Type' in address using API like 'Commercial' or 'Residential'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BigCommerce user defined custom fields for address and customer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443588/bigcommerce-user-defined-custom-fields-for-address-and-customer)